# error in if statement in r-missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r, if-statement, compiler-errors

I build this function in order to implement left_join in the "hard way". this is my code:

```
combined_2_df=function(df1,df2){
  my_df<-df1
  my_df$engine<-NA
  i=1
  while(i<=nrow(my_df)){
    for(j in 1: nrow(df2))
    {
      if (my_df$year[i]==df2$year[j])
      {
        my_df$engine[i]=df2$engine[j]
        break
      }#if
    }#for
    i=i+1
  }#while
  
  return(my_df)
}
```

however I got an error:

```
Error in if (my_df$year[i] == df2$year[j]) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

what I do wrong?
Thank you

Comment: @akrun what do you mean?

Comment: @akrun I dont want to use join method, I want to implement it by myself, I try to understand the error

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example

Comment: maybe you have `NA` values in data which cause this problem

Answer (score 0):

Your error message

```r
Error in if (my_df$year[i] == df2$year[j]) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

states that for some `i`, `my_df$year[i] == df2$year[j]` is not `TRUE` or `FALSE` but rather `NA`. The reason most likely is that either `my_df$year[i]` or `df2$year[j]` is `NA` for some `i` or `j`, respectively. So I suggest that you check your `my_df` for missing values.